# Python: extract the core of a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

Say I have a 2D numpy array like this:

```
In[1]: x
Out[1]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]], dtype=int64)
```

and I want to extract the `(n-1)*(m-1)` core, which would be:

```
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4]], dtype=int64)
```

How could I do this, since the data structure is not *flat*? Do you suggest flattening it first?

This is a simplified version of a much bigger array, which core has dimension `(n-33)*(n-33)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative stop indices to exclude the last x rows/columns and normal start indices:

```
>>> x[1:-1, 1:-1]
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

For your new example:

```
>>> t = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                  [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
                  [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]], dtype=np.int64)
>>> t[1:-1, 1:-1]
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4]], dtype=int64)
```

You could also remove 2 leading and trailing columns:

```
>>> t[1:-1, 2:-2]
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]], dtype=int64)
```

or rows:

```
>>> t[2:-2, 1:-1]
array([[2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I get this method would also work in the case of non-square arrays. To answer your last line, yes, in my case study `x=33`, but of course I know how many rows and columns are in my initial array.

Comment: `[1:-1]` means exclude first and last row, `[2:-2]` would exclude the first two and last two rows. Not sure what you mean with "not-square". I thought your `n` was the shape of your array.

Comment: I never said "non-rectangular", I just said "non-square". To be precise, I should have said my array is `m*n`. Check my edit.